# Quebra de página com fpdf php

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Eu estou gerando um relatório com fpdf usando php. Eu leio um arquivo csv e imprimo 3 colunas. Para cada coluna, eu criei um loop que imprime os dados. Dessa forma eu tenho um loop para cada coluna. Quando eu uso `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak` meu código imprime uma coluna em cada página. Isso ocorre quando a coluna ulprapassa o limite da página. Eu ja tentei desativar o `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak`  usando false, mas daí imprime além da margem. Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

```
 <?php
session_start();
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require_once ('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require('Header.php');
require('PageBreak.php');



//print($csvFile);
$fileName= '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/CreateReport/CLINICAL PLACEMENT REQUEST SURVEY  - Individual Attempts (2).csv';

ob_start();

function readCsv($fileName){
    $handle = fopen($fileName, "r");
    $data=array();
    while ($col = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) {   
        $data[] = [ 
            'Section' => $col[0],   
            'Q #' => $col [1],
            'Q Type' => $col[2],
            'Q Title' => $col[3],
            'Q Text' => $col[4],
            'Bonus' => $col [5],
            'Difficulty' => $col[6],
            'Answer' => $col[7],
            'Answer Match' => $col[8],
            'Responses'=> $col[9], 
        ];       
    }
    fclose($handle);


    return $data;
}

ob_end_flush();



function countLines($arr, $startLine){ //count blank lines btw sections   
$count=0;
$length= count($arr);

for($r=$startLine; $r<=$length; $r++){
        if((empty($arr[$r]['Section']))){
            $count+=1;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }

    return $count;
}




function cmp($a, $b) { 
  //  return $a['Answer Match'] > $b['Answer Match'] ; 
   return  strcmp($a['Answer Match'], $b['Answer Match']) ;

}


function countNumberOfElements( $column){
    $arrData= Array();
    $arrData= readCsv('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/CreateReport/CLINICAL PLACEMENT REQUEST SURVEY  - Individual Attempts (2).csv');
    $count=0;
    $length=count($arrData);
    for ($k=1; $k < $length; $k++) {
        if(!empty($arrData[$k][$column])){
            $count++;
        }   
    }
    return $count;
}


$page=

 "<html>

    <body>



    <h1> hello </h1>   
<br>   
    </body>   
</html>

    ";




// Converts file to pdf

function printPDF($page, $arrCVS)
{ 

    $marginLeft=25;
    $marginRight=25;
    $marginTop=30;

    $pdf = new PDF();

    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage('L');

    $pdf->SetMargins($marginLeft, $marginTop,  $marginRight, true);

    $fileOutput= "Report.pdf";
   $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,$marginTop );



    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica','',  10);
    $lineX=12; //space btw answers
    $lineY=5;
    $lenght=count($arrCVS); //array lenght

 for ($k=2; $k < $lenght; $k++) {

     if ($arrCVS[$k]['Answer']=="Health Science 5 (HSC)"){
         $arrCVS[$k]['Answer']="HSC";
     }else if ($arrCVS[$k]['Answer']=="St. Boniface (STB)"){
                 $arrCVS[$k]['Answer']="STB";
             } else 
                 if ($arrCVS[$k]['Answer']=="Grays Hospital (GRH)"){
                     $arrCVS[$k]['Answer']="GRH";
                 } else 
                     if ($arrCVS[$k]['Answer']=="Concordia (CON)"){
                         $arrCVS[$k]['Answer']="CON";
                    } 
                 else 
                     if ($arrCVS[$k]['Answer']=="Seven Oaks (SEO)"){
                         $arrCVS[$k]['Answer']="SEO";
                     }
                     else 
                         if ($arrCVS[$k]['Answer']=="Health Science 3 (HSA)"){
                             $arrCVS[$k]['Answer']="HSA";
                         }
                         else 
                             if ($arrCVS[$k]['Answer']=="Health Science 4 (HSB)"){
                                 $arrCVS[$k]['Answer']="HSB";
                             }          

            }

for ($x=2; $x < $lenght; $x++) {

    switch ($arrCVS[$x]['Answer']) {
        case "Personal (PE)":
        $arrCVS[$x]['Answer']=" PE ";
        break;

        case "Bison athlete (BA)":
            $arrCVS[$x]['Answer']=" BA  ";
            break;

        case "Work in Facility (WF)":
            $arrCVS[$x]['Answer']=" WF ";
            break;

        case "Live out of town (LT)":
            $arrCVS[$x]['Answer']=" LT ";
            break;
    }
}




//Display student name
$positionXname=$marginLeft;
$positionYname=$marginTop + ($marginTop*0.5);


$pdf->SetXY($positionXname, $positionYname);
$countStudents=0;

$countLines=0;

unset($arrCVS[0]); //skip line 1, header


for ($s=0; $s < $lenght; $s++) {
    if(!empty($arrCVS[$s]['Section']) OR $arrCVS[$s]['Section'] =! "Section #" ){
        $pdf->SetX($positionXname);
        $countStudents++;
        $countLines++;
        $pdf->Cell($lineX-5,$lineY,$countStudents,0,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell($lineX,$lineY,$arrCVS[$s]['Section'],0,1,'L');

    }

    if($countLines>24){
     //    $pdf->AddPage('L');
        $positionXname=25;
        $positionYname=30;
        $countLines=0;
    }

}






$lineXSites=12; //space btw answers
$lineYSites=5;
$marginLeftSites=25;
$marginRight=25;
$marginTopSites=30;

//Sites ranking
$positionXsites=$marginLeftSites + ($marginLeftSites*2);
$positionYsites=$marginTopSites + ($marginTopSites*0.5);
$positionXname=25;
$positionYname=30;

$pdf->SetXY($positionXsites, $positionYsites);
$lenght=count($arrCVS);
$numberOfStudents= countNumberOfElements('Section'); //ok
$startPoint=2;//2;

$perRowSites = 1;
for($student=0; $student< $numberOfStudents; $student++){
    $arr_Rank=(array_slice($arrCVS,  $startPoint,47)); //new array
    usort($arr_Rank, 'cmp');
    //Print 1 student
    for ($j=2; $j <47; $j++) {



        if(($arr_Rank[$j]['Q Type'])=="MAT" AND ($arr_Rank[$j]['Responses'])==1){
            $pdf->Cell($lineXSites,$lineYSites,$arr_Rank[$j]['Answer'],0,0,'L');
            $perRowSites++;

        }


        if(($perRowSites>6) OR ($arr_Rank[$j]['Answer Match'])=="UnChecked"){   //print 6 sites per row
            $pdf->Ln();
            $perRowSites=1;

            $pdf->SetX($positionXsites);
            break;

        }

    }
    $startPoint=$startPoint+47;

}//end $students


$lineXCon=12; //space btw answers
$lineYCon=5;
$marginLeft=25;
$marginRight=25;
$marginTop=30;


//Special considerations
$positionXcon=$marginLeft + ($marginLeft*6);
$positionYcon=$marginTop + ($marginTop*0.5);
$pdf->SetXY($positionXcon, $positionYcon);


unset($arrCVS[0]); //skip line 1, header
$perRow = 1;
$countLines=0;

for ($l=0; $l < $lenght; $l++) {



    if (($arrCVS[$l]['Answer Match'])=="UnChecked") {
        $perRow++;



        if(($arrCVS[$l]['Responses'])==1){
        $pdf->Cell($lineXCon,$lineYCon,$arrCVS[$l]['Answer'],0,0,'L'); 

        }

        if($perRow>4 ){
            $pdf->Ln();
            $perRow=1;
            $pdf->SetX($positionXcon);

        }



    }

} 

$pdf->Output('reports/'.$fileOutput, 'F');
}





printPDF($page,readCsv($fileName) );
session_destroy();

?>
```

Minha classe header.php

```
<?php


   require_once ('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{


    // Page header
    function Header()
{
    if ($this->page == 1)
    {
    $marginLeft=25;
    $marginRight=25;
    $marginTop=30;
    $this->SetFont('helvetica','B',12);
    $this->SetY(15);
    $this->Cell(0,25,'SITES RANKING REPORT',0,0,'C');
    $this->Ln(10);
    $this->SetXY(25, 30);
    $this->Cell(50,15,'STUDENT',0,0,'L',0);
    $this->Cell(65,15,'SITES',0,0,'C',0);
    $this->Cell(130,15,'CONSIDERATIONS',0,0,'C',0);
    $this->line($marginLeft, 45, 300- $marginRight, 45); // 25mm from each edge
    $this->Ln(20);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica','', 9);
    $this->SetXY($marginLeft+($marginLeft*0.25), $marginTop + ($marginTop*0.25));
    $this->Cell(150,10,'   1          2            3            4            5           6',0,0,'C',0);
    $this->SetXY($marginLeft+($marginLeft*5), $marginTop + ($marginTop*0.25));
    $this->Cell(120,10,'LT=Live out of town  WF=Work in facility  BA=Bison athlete  PE=Personal',0,0,'C',0);
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
    }
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    $marginLeft=25;
    $marginRight=25;
    $marginTop=30;
    $this->SetY(-15);
    $this->line($marginLeft,  215-$marginTop, 300- $marginRight,  215-$marginTop); // 30mm from each top bottom
    $this->SetFont('helvetica','', 9);
    $this->SetXY($marginLeft*3, 215-$marginTop);
    $this->Cell(150,10,'HSC=Health Science 5  STB=St. Boniface  CON=Concordia GRH=Grays Hospital  SEO=Seven Oaks  HSA=Health Science 3  HSB=Health Science 4',0,0,'C',0);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,25,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}



var $col = 0;

function SetCol($col)
{
    // Mudar de coluna
    $this->col = $col;
    $x = 10+$col*65;
    $this->SetLeftMargin($x);
    $this->SetX($x);
}

    function AcceptPageBreak()
    {
        //esquema de 3 colunas
        if($this->col<2)
        {
            // Avança para a próxima coluna
            $this->SetCol($this->col+1);
            $this->SetY(10);
            return false; //Não quebra a página
        }
        else
        {
            // Volta para a primeira coluna e quebra a página
            $this->SetCol(0);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

$pdf = new PDF(); //usa a sua implementação específica
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=300;$i++)
    $pdf->Cell(0,5,"Line $i",0,1);
    $pdf->Output();


$pdf->AliasNbPages();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vai ter que extender a class FPDF

O  método *AcceptPageBreak()* será chamado sempre que for necessário uma quebra de página, se estiver na última coluna terá que saltar para próxima página caso contrário salta para próxima coluna  e retorna falso.

Fonte: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/acceptpagebreak.htm

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
var $col = 0;

function SetCol($col)
{
    // Mudar de coluna
    $this->col = $col;
    $x = 10+$col*65;
    $this->SetLeftMargin($x);
    $this->SetX($x);
}

function AcceptPageBreak()
{
    //esquema de 3 colunas
    if($this->col<2)
    {
        // Avança para a próxima coluna
        $this->SetCol($this->col+1);
        $this->SetY(10);
        return false; //Não quebra a página
    }
    else
    {
        // Volta para a primeira coluna e quebra a página
        $this->SetCol(0);
        return true;
    }
}
}

$pdf = new PDF(); //usa a sua implementação específica
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=300;$i++)
$pdf->Cell(0,5,"Line $i",0,1);
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: _Jorge Costa : eu tenho chamar o $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak como true na minha classe principal? E se eu usar esse código dentro da minha classe Header.php isso vai funcionar? A minha classe Header estende  FPDF. Eu adicionei esse  código na minha classe Header.php e não funcionou. Não fez nenhuma alteraçnao no meu arquivo pdf.

Comment: _Jorge Costa: eu coloque true no $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak e agora a terceira coluna quegra a página e vai para a segunda página. No entando a 1a. e a 2a. coluna agora aparecem no topo da mesma página.

Comment: Publique o seu código para poder avaliar

Comment: _Jorge Costa atualizei minha pergunta com o código do meu programa.

Comment: $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,$marginTop ); será que está definir mal o limite da página, se não colocar nada terá uma margem por defeito de 2 cm

Comment: $marginTop é 30. Eu tentei usar 30, mas nao resolveu.

Comment: retire o SetAutoPageBreak e teste, mas não percebi o resultado pode colocar um screenshot

Comment: Comentei o SetAutoPageBreak , e não fez diferença. Coloquei o screenshot na pergunta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80681/discussion-between-jorge-costa-and-find83).

Comment: ok, eu entrei no chat

Comment: _Jorge Costa, o problema estava no lopp que imprimia as colunas. Criei funções e agiora funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: Parabéns por conseguir